# Lifetime of an object captured by reference in lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, lifetime

I have below c++ code.
Lambda is capturing a map object by reference and is able to access it after the life of that map object.

```
using VOID_VOID = std::function<void ()>;
using VOID_MAP = std::function<void (std::map<std::string, std::string> &)>;
using FUNC_MAP = std::function<VOID_VOID (std::map<std::string, std::string> &)>;

FUNC_MAP getLambda(VOID_MAP func)
{
    auto outer_lambda = [func](std::map<std::string, std::string> & m)->VOID_VOID {
        auto inner_lambda = [func, m]() mutable {
            m.erase("A");
            m["D"] = "4";
            func(m);
        };
        return inner_lambda;
    };
    return outer_lambda;
}

VOID_VOID test(FUNC_MAP f)
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> m = {{"A","1"}, {"C","3"}, {"B","2"}};
  return f(m);
}

int main()
{
  auto a = [](std::map<std::string, std::string> &z){
    for(auto p:z)
      std::cout << p.first << ":" << p.second << "\n";
  };
  auto outer_lambda = getLambda(a);
  auto fut = std::async (test, outer_lambda);
  auto inner_lambda = fut.get();

  auto fut2 = std::async (inner_lambda);
  fut2.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Output of above code is

```
B:2
C:3
D:4
```

Since the life of map object `m` is `test()` function, how is it still accessible from `inner_lambda` where it is captured by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the life of map object m is `test()`

The lifespan of `m` is the lifespan of the lambda which defines it (= captures it by value). That lambda is returned from `getLamda()`, and passed to the `std::async()` as `inner_lambda` in `main()`. So, it's alive and well inside the `fut2` future. `wait()`ing on the future executes `inner_lambda`, which erases the `A` and adds the `D`, and produces the output you see.